# Conversión de dato e imprimir un solo dato de consulta en Oracle

Tags: oracle-12c

Tengo el siguiente *query* para consultar las *tablespaces*:

```
select  a.TABLESPACE_NAME ,
        round(((a.BYTES-b.BYTES)/a.BYTES)*100,2) percent_used
from
    (select  TABLESPACE_NAME,
             sum(BYTES) BYTES
     from     dba_data_files
     group    by TABLESPACE_NAME
    )   a,
    (select  TABLESPACE_NAME,
             sum(BYTES) BYTES ,
             max(BYTES) largest
     from     dba_free_space
     group   by TABLESPACE_NAME
    ) b
where   a.TABLESPACE_NAME=b.TABLESPACE_NAME
order   by ((a.BYTES-b.BYTES)/a.BYTES) desc
```

Lo que deseo es que solo me imprima el valor en porcentaje. Cualquier aporte en valioso, gracias.

estos es lo que obtengo

´TABLESPACE_NAME                PERCENT_USED

UNDOTBS1                              92.71

SYSTEM                                85.93

TBS_STG_INDX                          72.96

TBS_STG_DATA                          68.98

SYSAUX                                 51.7

USERS                                 33.75

Comment: ¿Qué resultado estás obteniendo, y qué es lo que esperas obtener?

Comment: Envuelve tu query con otro select: `SELECT percent_used FROM ( TU_QUERY )`